# Adding parameters

Tags: java

I want to add parameters for the Input dialogs so that the program does not continue it they are empty. I am not sure how to do this please help.

```
try
{
    String query="insert into student (firstname,secondname,password) values (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1, JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name"));
    pst.setString(2, JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second Name"));
    pst.setString(3, JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your Password"));
    pst.execute();
    pst.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something Went Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant "parameters" :). What input ? The JOptionPane ? Have you done a search about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your code with a validation of the values, something like:

```
String firstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First Name");
String secondname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second Name");
String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your Password");

if(null == firstname || null == secondname || null == password)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing Parameters!");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        String query="insert into student (firstname,secondname,password) values (?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, firstname);
        pst.setString(2, secondname);
        pst.setString(3, password);

        pst.execute();

        pst.close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something Went Wrong!");
    }

}
```

Comment: no this is not working. it is not able to find words firstname, secondname, and password and underlining them in red in the "if statement".

Comment: See above - I revised my suggested code to first prompt the user for these parameters, then validate them, and only then go into the PreparedStatement logic.

Comment: (if this solved your problem and you have the option, please mark my response as the answer, thanks).